# Как подставить адрес отправителя при ответе на письмо?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подставить адрес отправителя при ответе на письмо? Благодарю!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["email"])){
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {$name = $_POST["name"];}
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {$email = $_POST["email"];}

if($name=="" or $email==""){
    echo "Заполните, пожалуйста, все поля!";
}else{
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$to = "mail@mail.ru";
$subject = "Заявка!";
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8;";
$headers = "From: <mail@mail.ru>";
$message = "Имя: $name \n E-mail: $email \n IP отправителя: $ip"; 
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if ($send == "true")
 {
 echo "Поздравляем! Ваша заявка принята!";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
 }
}
}
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On'); 
?>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в коде, переменная `$headers` перезаписывается и вы теряете отправителя в заголовке! Прочтите внимательней [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) mail php.

Answer (score 2):

Подробней здесь: [PHP Mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

```html
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      $name = $_POST["name"];
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
      $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    
    if ($name == "" or $email == "") {
      echo "Заполните, пожалуйста, все поля!";
    } else {
      $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      $to = "mail@mail.ru";
      $subject = "Заявка!";
      $headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8; \r\n"; // заголовок собирается из нескольких строк, делаем разрыв строки используя \r\n
      $headers .= "From: $name <$email>"; // нужно было использовать конкатенацю - Ошибка №1
      $message = "Имя: $name \n E-mail: $email \n IP отправителя: $ip"; 
      $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

      if ($send == true) { // функция отправки возвращает логическое true или false а не строку! Ошибка №2
        echo "Поздравляем! Ваша заявка принята!";
      } else {
        echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
      }
    }
  }
  ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On'); 
?>
```

Comment: @LADYX ооооо, вижу у вас совсем всё плохо со знаниями php и программированием в целом, попробуйте вот так: `$headers .= "From: Василий <$email>";` а Василий можете заменить на произвольный текст либо просто удалить! Я обновил ответ.

Comment: @LADYX Если в коде писать "<mail@mail.ru>", то и будет подставляться "<mail@mail.ru>"...

Comment: Уважаемый @LADYX, "кому" - это не отправитель, а получатель

Answer (score 0):

В `$email` ведь есть отправитель, вы можете подставить его в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решается так:

```
$headers = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8; \r\n Reply-To: <$email>";
```

Comment: То, что Reply-To это не адрес отправителя вам, надеюсь, понятно?

Comment: А это означает, что первоначальная задача так не решается.